# My house smells dusty/card boardy (no visible sign of extra dust)

Tags: cleaning

So this is something that has been bothering me for awhile. My 2 storey family home smells dusty/card boardy (Not sure if exactly dusty). I change air filters regularly and usually most carpets get vacummed using Roborock S4 every other day.

Downstairs where only one room is carpeted, we have to use our regular vacuum cleaner. We even have cleaners clean and vacuum the house every other week. We recently had air-ducts cleaned and I wet cleaned/washed the carpets few months back.

The thing that doesn't however get cleaned often is closets. And we have a walk-in attic full of boxes we kept from last time we moved (but it remains closed all the time).

I don't see any visible sign of dust and usually the smell is stronger when I come from vacation or something but you know how one gets used to it.

Answer (score 2):

Residential vacuums are pretty crap for fine dust capture.  The floor robot probably just puts all the fine dust into the air.  Carpets are impossible to clean perfectly.  If you ever pull a carpet there is so much dirt that has worked its way through the fibers.  They say after 10 years a carpet weighs twice as much as it did at install.  Get solid surface flooring and a central vac system.

What kind of filter do you have on your furnace, what is the merv rating?

Get some corsi-rosenthal boxes.  I bought the ones from cleanaircrew.org.

The other thing you might want to do is invest in airsealing.  If you get aerobarrier in then you can reduce the drafts that are being driven through your walls picking up any dust from the wall/joist/attic spaces that are brought into your house.  This assume you don't already have a tight (less than 1 ACH50) house.

Comment: I am using 16x25x1 filter. I use 3Ms 1200 or 1600 filters (so MERV 11).   I will look into other stuff but this is relatively a new house (2016 built) and far from forest fire or any industrial area (in Georgia).

Comment: get a PM2.5 air monitor and see if it detects the dust smell you are.  airthings.com sells them for $250

Comment: Thanks. I will check. My wife says it is not dusty but kinda card boardy (like how Amazon boxes smell). Could it be mold? I don't see any signs of mold though and we don't live near lake or anything either.

Comment: @Quixotic I would be concerned it's mold you smell.

Comment: How do u rule out mold? I will have to probably hire someone. I don't see any visible signs of mold activity tbh.  This thing is kinda puzzling

Comment: mold is a tough one.  You need two air tests.  The first air test is a background air test for spore counts outside.  The second air test would be an indoor air test and then you compare the counts.  mold grows outside on leaves, in dirt, on trees, etc.  There will always be spore counts.  Are you sick, immuno compromised, or pregnant?  Do you have allergy symptoms or is it just a smell?  I'd start with the cheap things, corsi box, change your filters, get rid of bedroom carpet, stop using the aerating vacuum.  The worst place to have mold is in your bedroom where you spend 8+ hours breathing.

Comment: the mold industry thrives on scare tactics though so i'd be hesitant to get a "mold" person in unless you have symptoms in which case you should ditch all your carpet as a first measure.

Comment: checking the attic for leaks is also worthwhile.  you can buy the little 150' endoscopes for $200 that can be pushed into your air vents as well to have a look.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! Yeah - I am personally very skeptical of mold. The house is dry (and in dry area), there haven't been any water leaks ever and there are no visible signs.  My plan is: a. Get a good quality vacuum cleaner (I am looking at Shark 352) and vacuum carpets and closets. b. Clean and dust floorboards.  c.  Get someone to take a look at HVAC. Does it stops blowing air when we are not in house?